# SQL Server Join query causing repeats

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that is combining two different tables that returns all the information I need, however it seems to be recreating extra rows with the same data and I can't seem to figure it out.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    [key], [ctankid], [dbo].[tbltanks].[csiteid],
    [dbo].[jobdata].[jobname], [ctankname], [ctanknameabbr],
    [cshousepartid], [cshousemodel], [csfiltermodel], [ddatecreated]
FROM 
    [sensordb].[dbo].[tbltanks]
JOIN
    jobdata ON [dbo].[tbltanks].[csiteid] = [dbo].[jobdata].[csiteid] 
WHERE
    cshousemodel IS NULL 
    AND csfiltermodel IS NULL
    AND ddatecreated > '2010-01-01'
ORDER BY 
    ddatecreated DESC
```

Results:

[image: Query results]

Comment: Tables might have `1:N` relation

Comment: Is there a way I can fix or limit that in the Query?

Comment: Use the `DISTINCT` keyword after `SELECT`. Best yet to understand why your assumptions that you should already have distinct records don't match your data.

Comment: Yeah, the databases I am working with were designed in Access about 20 years ago. I am trying to work with the data to build a couple different sales and service applications.

Comment: And yes, I did try DISTINCT and that did not do the job.... I was hoping it would but there were a few Dups that carried over.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a situation where you have a one to many relationship.  Because of this there are multiple records in the child table.

Now the question is how to determine which record to select. This is a business rule and cannot properly be answered by us. However, I can make some suggestions.

First, is it some field not being returned that is causing two records to be returned?  If so then DISTINCT should fix the problem. Note that distinct is not necessarily going to be a fast solution. If you have performance problems using distinct, you may need to consider a where clause to limit the records instead.

If the multiple records have different values for one or more of the fields being returned, they are not necessarily repeats. It might be that you need to return both records, or it might be that you need to add a where clause on the query to limit the records in the child table to the one you want. For instance, if you were querying addresses, then you might want to select a particular address type so that you get only one record. What that where clause might be is a business rule that can only come from your business requirements.

Another possibility is that you need to aggregate the values for one or more fields instead. So GROUP BY and aggregate functions might be what you need. Again, this comes down to what is your particular business rule.